# Forward only a single group using the WirePattern helper when config.group is true

Tags: noflo

I'm trying to use the WirePattern helper to perform some synchronisation within my graph. I'm setting `config.group` to true so I can ensure that only packets received with the same group are collected and handled within this component.

For the sake of argument, here is an example packet from the first in-port:

```
<my-group>
123
</my-group>
```

And the second in-port:

```
<my-group>
456
</my-group>
```

Because `config.group` is set to true, these 2 packets will match by group and I can do something with them in my component. So far so good.

The problem lies in that I want to wrap the output with the same group that the 2 in-ports were matched by. This is what the out packet group should look like:

```
<my-group>
123456
</my-group>
```

I assumed `config.group` would do this by default but it doesn't, it just sends the output with no group:

```
123456
```

I tried setting `config.forwardGroups` to various values in an effort to forward the group from only one of the in-ports (seeing as they're identical). Regardless of whether this is set to `true`, `"portname"` or `["portname"]`, it double-wraps the out packet:

```
<my-group>
<my-group>
123456
</my-group>
</my-group>
```

This causes headaches further down the line as the grouping has changed and no longer matches up with the other components. I could manually remove one of the groups using another component, but I shouldn't have to do that.

**How can I set up the WirePattern to continue matching by group (using `config.group`) but only forward a single group to the out port?**

I don't mind doing it manually for now if this is something that the WirePattern doesn't support. I just need to know whether I'm doing something wrong, or whether it's just not possible in NoFlo yet.

Here's my config for reference:

```
var config = {
  in: ["in", "value"],
  params: ["property"],
  out: "out",
  // This doesn't forward the group
  group: true, // Wait for packets of same group
  // This duplicates groups when group: true
  forwardGroups: ["value"],
  arrayPolicy: {
    in: "all", // Wait for all indexes
    params: "all" // Wait for all indexes
  }
};
```

Comment: I think I've seen this issue sometime before, in which case I worked around by setting the component to WirePattern async mode. But hopefully Vladimir can provide clarification on the right way to configure it soon.

Comment: Aha, well that matches up with my current solution (using async) which I discovered after digging through the source code for the WirePattern helper. It'd be good to know whether WirePattern should / can support this without async.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me as I remember enforcing group uniqueness upon forwarding. I've opened https://github.com/noflo/noflo/issues/269 and will fix it by next NoFlo release.

For now, another workaround would be: don't use `forwardGroups` feature but rather send groups manually to the output inside the process handler (which is absolutely legal when using WirePattern too):

```
out.beginGroup(groups[0]);
out.send(input.in + input.value);
out.endGroup();
```

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue, I'll keep an eye on it. I thought about manually passing on the group but if `config.group = true` then I don't receive any groups in the process handler `groups` array so I can't access them to manually pass them on.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the desired behavior either, will investigate.